# stripe cardForm is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, payment, strip, card

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEs1E.png)i am integrating stripe payment gateway want to use cardForm but facing issue

expecting to cardForm

Comment: please add your image to the question or copy error as text

Answer (score 1):

you need add setup theme in style.xml file, cardForm required material so you need install this. but this set up will change some thing in theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
     <item name="android:colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]add this to the build/app.

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'